# Muzzle Velocity confusion

Tags: velocity, relative-motion

Does muzzle velocity refer to the velocity of the bullet with respect to ground or the velocity with respect to the gun?

Comment: Wouldn't those usually be the same? Must be quite some recoil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the velocity with respect to the end of the gun barrel. However, it is probably an imprecise term because if you want it down to the mm/s you would have to subtract the recoil speed of the gun. In practice people just measure the velocity with respect to a closely spaced meter on the bench and assume the gun recoil is negligible, as well as the deceleration of the bullet once it has exited and during measurement.

Answer (score 0):

Muzzle speed of the bullet means velocity of the bullet with respect to the velocity of the gun.