# Why does bullet falls on the earth if shooter moving back at same speed of firing?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, projectile

My friend told me if a shooter moving back at same speed of firing, so when he fires then bullet comes out of the gun and falls on the ground without hitting the target.

[image]

I am amazed by this phenomenon, what exactly is happening?

Comment: Velocities are added and $v+(-v)=0$. Check for [Galilean transformation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/342519/75633). You'll also probably enjoy the video [Mythbusters - Soccer Ball Shot from Truck](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLuI118nhzc).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of previous research effort.

Comment: It boils down to the appreciation of the fact that the x, y, and z components of a body's velocity are independent.

Comment: The bullet is moving backwards to begin with, since it is contained in the gun.  So, when you fire the gun in the opposite direction, the backwards movement of the bullet slows down and stops.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special. Velocities are added. The bullet travels with its ordinary muzzle velocity **relative to the gun**, but since the gun travels with this same velocity in the **opposite direction**, the net result is that the bullet is **not moving relative to Earth**, and since gravity pulls it down, it falls to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the velocity of the gun to velocity of the bullet after firing. Since the two are opposite and equal in magnitude the result is that the bullet has zero velocity. Like  a bullet at any speed it is downward accelerated by gravity. In thus case it falls straight to the ground.

Answer (score 0):

If you read this webpage, [muzzle velocity confusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/162817/muzzle-velocity-confusion), you will realise that you question which mentions *speed of firing* is ambiguous although in practical terms the difference between the speed of the bullet relative to the ground is approximately equal  to the speed of the bullet relative relative to the gun (muzzle velocity) because the mass of the gun is much larger than the mass of the bullet.

If you have a gun, mass $m_{\rm gun}$ and bullet, mass $m_{\rm bullet}$ at rest relative to the ground the total momentum is zero.

If the gun is not constrained in any way horizontally then after the gun has been fired the total horizontal momentum of the bullet and the gun is still zero although the bullet has horizontal momentum $m_{\rm bullet}v_{\rm bullet,ground}$ as does the gun $m_{\rm gun}v_{\rm gun,ground}$ such that $m_{\rm bullet}v_{\rm bullet,ground} + m_{\rm gun}v_{\rm gun,ground} = 0$ with the horizontal velocities being relative to the ground.

If, before being fired, the gun was moving at a speed of $v_{\rm bullet,ground}$ in the opposite direction to that which the bullet would be travelling after the gun was fired then after firing the horizontal velocity of the bullet relative to the ground would be zero just as your friend told you and the gun would be travelling slightly faster.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a conceptial question of relative velocity. When a person fires a bullet the bullet leaves the gun with a relative velocity of v but in this case as the person is moving opposite to the target the bullet will also have a velocity in that opposite direction & since the speed of firing =speed of shooter the bullet acquire a net velocity of 0 & fall due to gravity